# How can I search in XML file with SearchView?

Tags: android

I wish to search in XML file with SearchView. The data from XML is parsed in a ListView. I haven't idea for displayResults method.
This is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
     Bundle appData = new Bundle();
     appData.putBoolean(MainActivity.JARGON, true);
     startSearch(null, false, appData, false);

     return true;
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    setIntent(intent);
    handleIntent(intent);
}

private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
      doMySearch(query);
    }
}

private void doMySearch(String query) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope you mean search items in ListView with search in XML file, since ListView contains data from XML. So here is how to do it, there is a [great tutorial](http://www.myandroidsolutions.com/2013/08/04/android-listview-with-searchview/) here. You should check it out if you haven't already.

Now I assume you successfully parsed your data to ListView, so I'm skipping that part. There is some layout files you have to create first which you can find from the link above. Then just use this:

```
inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
    // When user changed the Text
    MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
        int arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
}
});
```

Here the `inputSearch` is a EditText, TextWatcher will handle the job for you.

Comment: No, I'm using SearchView